# How to stop backspace or delete key to delete text before the cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to stop cursor from deleting the word before it if the word before is "Hi Harry" in input type text . I am trying to restrict cursor from deleting text, if user started deleting text and 
text before it matches "Hi Harry" before it then stop deleting this text. The user also should not override the "Hi Harry text" by selecting and typing another character. "Hi Harry" must not be deleted or replaced by user by any action.

Any solution that fulfills the requirement may help.

## .html

```
<input id="target" type="text" value="Hi Harry">
```

## js

```
$( "#target").keydown(function(e) {
   if (e.which == 8 && e.target.value === "Hi Harry") { 
    // backspace or delete key

            return false;  

// here I want to stop cursor from deleting if user started deleting text and 
//text before it if matches "Hi Harry" then stop deleting this text.
        }

    });
```

Comment: Your example is working (with backspace=8) unless you didnt enclosed the code with the jquery ready

Comment: what about if the user select the text with the keyboard? Or the mouse? and then replace it pressing a key is not backspace? Or dragging the selection? What about if the text selected overlap with "Hi Harry"?

Comment: @Zero, this is also the requirement how can it be achieved.

Comment: if you don;t want to edit that particular text box i think you should add disabled properties that easy for you can handle with out keydown function check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may know by now, to prevent the user from deleting with <kbd>backspace</kbd> or <kbd>delete</kbd>, you can preventDefault on the events for `e.which == 8` or `e.which == 46`.

What if the user selects the text or clicks in between "Hi Harry?" You need to also handle some text selection events. See the snippet below<sup>[1]</sup>:

```js
// monitor key down function
var initialValue = $("#target").val();

$("#target").keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.target.selectionStart < initialValue.length) {
    //prevent user from typing stuff in between "Hi Harry"
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
  if ((e.which == 8 || e.which == 46) && e.target.value === initialValue) {
    // backspace or delete key
    // backspace is 8, delete is 
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
// monitor text selection and force to deselect
function handleSelections(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var endPoint = initialValue.length;
  if (e.target.selectionEnd > initialValue.length + 1) {
    endPoint = e.target.selectionEnd;
  }
  if (e.target.selectionStart < initialValue.length) {
    e.target.setSelectionRange(initialValue.length, endPoint);
  };
}
// prevent any selection of text until after "Hi Harry"
$("#target").get(0).addEventListener('select', handleSelections);
// prevent cursor positioning anywhere within "Hi Harry"
$("#target").get(0).addEventListener('click', handleSelections);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="target" type="text" value="Hi Harry">
```

<sup>[1]</sup> Tested on Google Chrome 78

Answer (score 1):

You could just call the [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) method of the `event` argument that is passed to the callback function when these conditions are met :

- <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> (`e.which === 8`) is being pressed.
- the `input`'s value is currently equals to `Hi Harry`.

> a better approach is to store the initial value of `input` thus you'll be able to write anything as its initial value.

```js
const inp = $("#target"), /** referening the input **/
  initVal = inp.val(); /** store its initial value **/

/** keydown event handler **/
inp.on('keydown', e => {
  e.which == 8 && inp.val() == initVal && e.preventDefault();
  /**
  * backspace and current value is the same as the initial value then just don't allow the backpace functionnality at this moment.
  * if the conditions aren't met, simply the line won't work thus allow inputing.
  **/
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="target" type="text" value="Hi Harry">
```

Comment: Thanks ths, how the "Hi Harry text" must not be replaced by any other character by selecting and typing any other key.

Comment: @Mahi I've shared an implementation that should do just that :)